# How do you create an object after a certain time?

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

I'd like to create a cube 5 seconds after pressing the "Run Script" button. Please let me know how to program it.

Comment: You can keyframe objects visibility

Comment: Worth reading https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the time library in python.

```
import time

print("foo")
time.sleep(5000) # this will cause the program to wait 5 seconds (5000 ms)
print("bar")

# the program will print "foo", wait 5 seconds and then print "bar"
```